# How can I edit the text in the letter's \encl{} command?

Tags: templates, letters

When using the `\encl{}` command along with the Dutch babel, 'encl:' will be translated to 'Bijlage(n)'.

'Bijlage(n)' can be translated as 'Attachment(s)': it may be plural or singular.

However, I know that there will be only one attachment, so I want it to be printed as 'Bijlage'. How can I do that?

*Minimal working example:*

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\signature{Mr Bond}
\address{My address \\ 
         My zip code \\
         My city}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Address \\ 
               Zip code \\
               City}
\opening{Hello,}
Bla, bla bla.

Bla bla bla? Bla!

\closing{Regards,}
\encl{Top-secret manuscript}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line after `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\enclname}{Bijlage}
```

This redefines the text in the `\enclname` command.

Comment: Most certainly is `\encl` an option too, but it isn't really formal or desirable. Even though it doesn't really matter here. For example, when the macro also does quite a lot of formatting. You would lose that in such a case. Therefore, redefining `\enclname` is more desirable.

Comment: Please remove the second `\renewcommand`; it's wrong. Your original answer is good, provided no change of language is used in the document and the `\renewcommand` you propose is *after* `\begin{document}`, which probably Exeleration-G didn't consider. A different place could be just before `\encl`; it could even make more sense there.

Comment: It was changed by Exeleration-G, but not with an explanation of why it didn't work. Most likely indeed the \renewcommand before the document. I will change it again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read over 'after the begin of the document'. Putting it after `\begin{document}` worked, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The correct method is to modify `\captionsdutch`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\addto\captionsdutch{\renewcommand{\enclname}{Bijlage}}

\signature{Mr Bond}
\address{My address \\ 
         My zip code \\
         My city}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Address \\ 
               Zip code \\
               City}
\opening{Hello,}
Bla, bla bla.

Bla bla bla? Bla!

\closing{Regards,}
\encl{Top-secret manuscript}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]